# Splunk logging with transaction

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

1) I want to count the number of occurences of the HTTP URL with p(95) response time for url invocation:
https://example.net/v1/abc/xyz with the response code as 200 or 500
2) The response time is the difference of time-stamp b/w line 6 & 3.
3) Both the URL invocation & Status code occurs for the same thread which is Thread-30_Server_1 and always should be the next occurences
If you see both event 1 & event 2 occur with the same thread but the response status code should always be sequential.
So the splunk search should return event 1 with Status as 200 where-as event 2 with Status as 350

Below is the extract from the logs:
    Event 1:

```
Line1) 2017-11-10 03:05:38,826 10606295 INFO  (Thread-30_Server_1:) :Url in else part is:https://example.net/v1/abc/xyz
Line2) 2017-11-10 03:05:38,826 10606295 INFO  (Thread-30_Server_1:) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Line3) 2017-11-10 03:05:38,826 10606295 INFO  (Thread-30_Server_1:) HTTP url : https://example.net/v1/abc/xyz
Line4) 2017-11-10 03:05:38,826 10606295 INFO  (Thread-30_Server_1:) Body: [{"itemID":"42650750083","uom":"EACH","toZipCode":"112173111","qty":1,"channel":"dotcom"}]
Line5) 2017-11-10 03:05:38,826 10606295 INFO  (Thread-30_Server_1:) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Line6) 2017-11-10 03:05:39,012 10606481 INFO  (Thread-30_Server_1:) :Status Code is:200
Line7) 2017-11-10 03:05:39,012 10606481 INFO  (Thread-30_Server_1:) :Status message is:"Success"
Line8) 2017-11-10 03:05:39,012 10606481 INFO  (Thread-30_Server_1:) Exit call and 3
```

Event 2:

```
Line101) 2017-11-10 03:05:39,364 10606833 INFO  (Thread-30_Server_1:) Enter call with 5 attributes
Line102) 2017-11-10 03:05:39,364 10606833 INFO  (Thread-30_Server_1:) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Line103) 2017-11-10 03:05:39,364 10606833 INFO  (Thread-30_Server_1:) HTTP url : https://example.net/v2/mmm/nnn
Line104) 2017-11-10 03:05:39,364 10606833 INFO  (Thread-30_Server_1:) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Line105) 2017-11-10 03:05:39,442 10606911 INFO  (Thread-30_Server_1:) ####################################################################
Line106) 2017-11-10 03:05:39,442 10606911 INFO  (Thread-30_Server_1:) Output from Server
Line107) 2017-11-10 03:05:39,442 10606911 INFO  (Thread-30_Server_1:) {"status":350,"message":"Success","body":[{"shortageQty":0,"reservedQty":1,"partiallyReservedQty":0,"problemType":"SUCCESS"}}]}
Line108) 2017-11-10 03:05:39,442 10606911 INFO  (Thread-30_Server_1:) ####################################################################
Line109) 2017-11-10 03:05:39,442 10606911 INFO  (Thread-30_Server_1:) :Status Code is:350
Line110) 2017-11-10 03:05:39,442 10606911 INFO  (Thread-30_Server_1:) :Status message is:"Success"
Line111) 2017-11-10 03:05:39,442 10606911 INFO  (Thread-30_Server_1:) Exit call
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, why is your Splunk timestamp different than the logs timestamp? You need to apply base configs to your props.conf for proper titmestamping and linebreaking. I would address this issue before doing anything else.

You second portion could be solved with combining 2 lines into a single event then adding a `where` clause to only return events with both status=200 AND status=350